# Sharing code between AngularJS and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, bower

What is the best way of sharing code between frontend and backend using `javascript`, specifically saying between `nodejs` and `angularjs`?

Thing is that we are using same `enums` and `constant values` such as `error codes` in both backend and frontend. Right now we just copy&paste each change to both platform which isn't a good solution. There are also some services that could be shared.

I have seen libraries such as `browserify`; but thats not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for a solution similar to `maven dependency` in `java`. In `java`, libraries can be shared easily using `maven`, whereas I can't find a similar way of doing that in `javascript`.
Is there a way to isolate these services and give them as dependency to `nodejs` using `npm` and to `angularjs` using `bower` independently? Or what are the ways for sharing the same code between frontend and backend?

Comment: browserify allows you to use common js modules in the client.  it is nothing like copy and pasting.

Comment: I feel like this can be solved with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) if you wanted something simpler than browserify. And I agree with @tkone, browserify isn't copy/pasting. Sure, it's replicating your common lib into another file, but that would be equivalent to saying compiling code is copy/pasting the source into binaries.

Comment: @tony not even replicating.  it's that ACTUAL file. `require` is shimmed into the browser, allowing the same exact code to be used. it even does the familiar `function(__dirname,...` wrapping that node does (because it lets node do it for you!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  The first is that you can make a new package which is required via bower for the front-end code and via npm for the backend code.  I have several packages published to both systems.

[Install with Bower](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install) -- information on how to install modules that aren't in the registry

[NPM Install docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) -- all the ways to install with npm (private github with auth: `git+ssh://git@github.com/[org]/[repo]`)

Just create a new module with your shared data and install it using both package managers.  Both of them allow you to install an unpublished module so if it's private data you can keep it as such.

If your front end requires `require.js` you can use something like [`amdefine`](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine) to make it available to your node backend, or if you're just using legacy window code you can do something like:

```
var mydata = {};

if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    window.mydata = mydata;
} else {
     module.exports = mydata;
}
```

If you are sharing a lot of data though I highly recommend looking into browserify to write your entire codebase in commonjs and using browserify to generate your client bundle. There is a [laundry list of resources](http://browserify.org/articles.html) about using browserify, including stuff on how to [use browserify and angular together](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/angular-browserify-grunt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - I'm still developing this approach and it's a little manual.
I did this using npm, an npm cli called [pac](https://github.com/mikefrey/node-pac), and bower. Pac let's me avoid using `npm install` in production by keeping the modules as .tgz files (committed to project in source control). With pac, when someone checks out the node project, they run `pac install` then `npm rebuild` instead of `npm install`.

My shared code is kept in a directory (my-module). It has both package.json and a bower.json.

My consuming node app has a package.json dependency for:
"my-module" : "x.y.z"

My consuming client has a bower.json dependency for:
"my-module" : "../relative/path/to/my-module"

When I make updates to my-module, I update my node app by:

1. Making a tar.gz of the contents of my-module:
   `tar -czvf my-module.tar.gz -C my-module`
2. Removing the old version from the node app's node_modules
3. Rerunning `npm install path/to/my-module-tar.gz`
4. Rerunning pac (this makes a .tgz of node_modules/my-module)
5. Committing the updated pac .modules/my-module.tgz

I update my client by:

1. Removing the old client/bower_components/my-module
2. Rerunning `bower install` or `bower update`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiencie, is very useful to me :)