# How to share code between Angular 8 and NodeJS 12

Tags: node.js, angular

Is it possible to share code between Angular 8 (TypeScript) and NodeJS 12?

The code all resides on the same server in separate directories `/client` and `/server`.

The problem we are running into is that we have a large amount of regular expressions and other constants that are being duplicated across Angular and Node and we are wondering if there's a way to share code to reduce duplication, perhaps by creating and importing modules.

There seems to be some workarounds for the old AngularJS.

[Sharing code between AngularJS and Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069777/sharing-code-between-angularjs-and-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

For your regular expressions, you can create a private npm package, and use it in both node and angular

For private npm package, you need to pay subscriptions. ([7$ month](https://www.npmjs.com/products) )